# "inspect" window in eclipse 3.6 doesn't remember being resized

Tags: eclipse

Prior to eclipse 3.6, in the debug perspective, you could "inspect" variables by highlighting them and hitting ctrl+shift+i. you could then resize the popup window and eclipse remembered what size it was the next time you inspected something.

In eclipse 3.6, you can inspect variables, but regardless of whether you resize the window, the next time you inspect something, the window goes back to its default size.  That's annoying because I like that window to be nice and big.

Is there any way to set eclipse to remember the size of this window, or is it a bug?

Comment: It's pretty annoying to me also. Default size is very small :-(

Comment: I reported it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332387

Comment: And in the followups to @Ant's bug, it looks like it's changed in 3.7 (not yet released).

Comment: doh... if you hit ctrl+shift+i or select "inspect" from the context menu, it now works again.  if you simply hover, the window always has the same mini size...  im going to update the bug coz im not satisfied.

Comment: @AntKutschera is right; it's not fixed in 3.7, unfortunately.  The popup window is always tiny.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans to back-port any of the work we did for pop-up resizing to 3.6.x, so unfortunately you will have to update to 3.7.x.