# Resizing yellow box on Eclipse and keeping it sized

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I've been trying to resize the yellow box that appears when I press Ctrl+Shift+I over a variable or so, but every time I resize it, it comes to its actual size again.
I know it's possible to resize and keep it this size, but can't remember how. Can you guys remind me?

Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I does nothing in my Eclipse Helios when editing a Java file

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I only works while stopped during debugging.  This command evaluates the currently selected expression (very handy!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under your workspace, open

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.ui/dialog_settings.xml
```

under workbench section, modify these keys,

```
<item value="300" key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.InspectPopupDialogDIALOG_WIDTH"/>
<item value="300" key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.InspectPopupDialogDIALOG_HEIGHT"/>
<item value="4"   key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.InspectPopupDialogDIALOG_Y_ORIGIN"/>
<item value="192" key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.InspectPopupDialogDIALOG_X_ORIGIN"/>
```

Comment: Firstly close your eclipse. Modify values then restart. It should work.

Comment: hmm really interesting! it works in my machine without any problem.

Comment: my SO is ubuntu, maybe it works on windows.. I hope yours is windows lol

Comment: i don't think it is an os related problem. You should check your dialog_settings.xml. Maybe there is a typo. By the way i am using linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a good deal of development on the Eclipse platform.  When an Eclipse developer provides a popup like this they have the option of providing a menu that will let the end user (you in this case) save the size.  In this case it appears that the developer choose not to expose this menu.

Also, I searched my Eclipse preferences and there is no option to turn this on.

Someone else might be able to provide a different solution but, I think you're out of luck.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be resized on Windows the traditional way ... I can't speak to the other operating systems.

However, I came across this method of adjusting the settings from an eclipse bug report and it may work for you:

```
${myWorkspaceDir}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/dialog_settings.xml
```

Add this section (be careful, it might already exist but it should be empty) :

```
<section name="completion_proposal_size">
    <item value="800" key="size.x"/>
    <item value="300" key="size.y"/>
</section>
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: I know it can be resized because someone from my past work station did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out and in my case, when I resize the popup window, the size is remembered, ie, the next time I do Ctrl-Shift-I to open the window, it's the same size as what I resized it to. The size is maintained between debug sessions. I haven't done anything special, so in my case it must be default behaviour. Just to add that I'm using JBoss Developer Studio 3.0.0 GA, which is basically Eclipse Galileo (3.5.2).

On further investigation, it would appear that this issue is mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795471/inspect-window-in-eclipse-3-6-doesnt-remember-being-resized) on here and that this "not remembering the size" issue was introduced with Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).

Comment: Well, that's my eclipse... Helios :(

Comment: @pringlesinn so, do I get the bounty for correctly answering your question? ..even though it's not the answer you wanted ;-)